# laravel 5 validation custom error message not appear

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to show the custom validation error message if user upload an image size of more than 4 MB. However, once submitted with an image of like above 4MB, it shows the default error message : "The file name failed to upload.". Below is my code in the controller:

```
$messages = [
            'fileName' => 'Image maximum size exceed. ',
];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'fileName' => 'max:4096', 
        ], $messages);

if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
        }
```

Here is the HTML code in the blade file:

```
<input type="file" name="fileName">
```

Comment: use `fileName.max` in your `$messages` array

Comment: @rkj done as 'fileName.max' => 'Image maximum size exceed. ', ---- but the same message showing.

Comment: did you set max_file_size value higher in php.ini file ?

Comment: Maybe this? resources/lang/en/validation.php     'custom' => [
        'attribute-name' => [
            'fileName' => 'custom-message',
        ],
    ],

Comment: @Bas I want to do the custm message by writing in the controller

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I have to post this answer here. This was what worked for me

```
$messages = [
            'fileName.uploaded' => 'Image maximum size exceed. ',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this line:

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->customMessages);
```

and it solved the problem.

Comment: This doesn't work if I need to validate for multiple rules, it only returns the `customMessage`